# How to verify if the objects in a list are all having parent child relationship in java

Tags: java, parent-child

I am having a List of categories, and I am trying to find if the categories are all related to each other. For Example, HW, Phones, Iphone and 13 Pro are the categories. Each Category will have fields categoryid and parentId.

HW -> Phones -> IPhone -> 13 Pro

In above case, HW has parentId as null since it is a root, Phones has parentId as HW, Iphone has parentId as Phones, and 13 Pro has parent id as IPhone.
I want to validate the parent child relationship along with the order of the categories( meaning, 13 Pro is a child of Iphone, Iphone is a child of Phones, Phones is a child of HW and If they are not in the order, ex: HW -> 13 Pro -> IPhone -> Phones , then I need to throw error saying the order is incorrect), as I get this List from an external service. Also the order could not be hierachial. The list could be in any order. I am trying to write a Java code for the same. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
List<Category> categoryList = getCategoryList();
categoryList.stream().forEach(category -> {
    if (category.getParentId().isEmpty()) {
        String rootCategory = category.getId();
        if (category.getParentId().equals(rootCategory)) {
            String category2 = category.getId();
            if (category.getParentId().equals(category2)) {
                String category3 = category.getId();
                if (category.getParentId().equals(category3)) {
                    String category4 = category.getId();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please indent your code so it's readable, and also add expected input and output?

Comment: `I want to validate the parent child relationship,`, this is not clear. You should reword what you want as output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to traverse the tree in both directions so you need to build a data structure that reflects this.

Add a parentCategory field to your Category class, plus a List of child categories. Initialise these new fields in a new method Category getCategoryTree() which will return the root category.

Initialising the tree is a little tricky, but once done you will be able to navigate freely up and down the category hierarchy.